# Expressing curvature as a limit (do Carmo 1.7 Exercise 4)

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I've been trying to solve the following problem:

Let $C$ be a plane curve and let $T$ be the tangent line at a point $p \in C$. Draw a line $L$ parallel to the normal line at $p$ and at a distance $d$ of $p$. let $h$ be the length of the segment determined on $L$ by $C$ and $T$. Prove that $\lvert k(p) \rvert = \lim_{d \to 0} \frac{2h}{d^2}$ where $k(p)$ is the curvature of $C$ at $p$.[image]

Comment: thank you @Thomas. I fixed it

Comment: To answer that, you need a definition of the curvature. What have you been given ?

Comment: the norm of the second derivative of the position vector

Comment: So can't you use the Taylor development to get a relation between $d$ and $h$ that involves the second derivative at $p$ ?

Comment: that's a good idea. I will try to do that

Comment: It worked @YvesDaoust. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to know ! ($h(d)\approx h(0)+d h'(0)+d^2 h''(0)/2=d^2 h''(0)/2$.)